# When stripe verification fails why am I not being shown a flash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, if I purposely make the card decline, I get shown the error page. Like so:
[image]
Instead of  an error page I want to be notified with a flash instead. I have the below code, but why am I not alerted using a flash?

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    def new 

    end


    def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 100

    # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:email],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    begin
      Stripe::Charge.create(
          :amount => @amount,
          :currency => 'usd',
          :customer => customer.id,
          :description => 'Example charge custom form'
      )

      current_user.subscribed = true
      current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
      current_user.expiry_date = Date.today + 30.days
      current_user.save


      flash[:success] = "Thank you for subscribing. Your account has been unlocked."
      redirect_to root_path

      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to root_path
    end


end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one, just to see the result.

Don't put the flash or redirection. Use `raise` or something else just to see where the code get caught.

```
begin
  # Use Stripe's library to make requests...
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  # Since it's a decline, Stripe::CardError will be caught

rescue Stripe::RateLimitError => e
  # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
rescue Stripe::AuthenticationError => e
  # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
rescue Stripe::APIConnectionError => e
  # Network communication with Stripe failed
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
  # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  # yourself an email
rescue => e
  # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
end
```

Comment: I don't think this changes anything, unless I'm missing something!

Comment: Have you tried it though? `rescue => e` should catch something if all the other `rescue` didn't do anything.